# Python Plotting via Matplotlib - Can't get xlabel and ylabel to show up on plot

Tags: python, numpy, plot, matplotlib

Here is a snippet of some running code. The plot generates, however, the xlabel and ylabel won't show up for some reason.

```
    pl.ion()
    pl.plot(t[1000:10000:250],E_values,'ro')
    pl.xlabel('Time')
    pl.ylabel('Concentration')
    pl.legend(['[E2F]'],loc='lower right')
    pl.show()
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm on Mac OS X.Thank you.

Comment: Which backend are you using? I'm also on Mac OS X; with the native backend, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my own problem - sorry, it's late. The `label` and `legend` commands should come before the call to `plot`. The following works:

```
    pl.ion()
    pl.xlabel('Time')
    pl.ylabel('Concentration')
    pl.legend(['[E2F]'],loc='lower right')
    pl.plot(t[1000:10000:250],E_values,'ro')
    pl.show()
```

Comment: This is odd, since your original code works fine for me (albeit on Linux). Perhaps something with the backend. In the end, `pl.show()` should do any final rendering, so the labels and legends can be placed after `plot()`.

Comment: @evert I suspect that there is something fishy going on with the figure manager and the interactive session being in a strange state.

Comment: W.r.t. to EOL's comment: try and see if you can use another backend. Not saying it will resolve the issue, but worth a try if you can easily switch between backend.